# Neural Network Not Converging "anywhere"

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation

In the past 2 weeks I've been trying to implement a Hand-Written-Digit Classifier with a Feed-Forward Neural Network, using the MNIST Database.
The neural network uses Cross-Entropy loss, and Softmax for the output layer; The rest of the nodes are activated with a Sigmoid function.

The main problem I encountered while training the network, was that the loss never converged and was very spastic.

I've already tried to re-write my script, check if I implemented the Math correctly, and I've had no luck with it. I also read other posts with the same problem, but none of them gave me an answer I looked for. Furthermore, I tried checking with a simpler neural network but no luck either.
Sources I've used in my code:
[Backpropagation By Ken-Chen](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/gradient-descent-backpropagation-ken-chen)
[Derivative of Softmax With Cross-Entropy](https://peterroelants.github.io/posts/cross-entropy-softmax/)
[Example to Feed-Forward and Backpropagation](http://galaxy.agh.edu.pl/%7Evlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html)

**Note** I'm pretty sure the problem occurs when I'm updating the weights, but I cant tell.
**Note** The code below is the re-written script.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
from mnist import MNIST


class Neural_Re:
    def __init__(self, layers):
        self.layers = layers
        self.weights = []
        self.bias_weights = [0 for i in range(len(layers) - 1)]
        self.activated_sums = []
        self.derivative_sums = []
        self.learning_rate = 0.1

        self.error = []

        # Initialize Random Weights
        for i in range(len(layers) - 1):
            weights_matrix = np.random.rand(self.layers[i + 1], self.layers[i]).dot(
                np.sqrt(2 / (self.layers[i] + self.layers[i + 1])))
            self.weights.append(weights_matrix)

    def add_bias(self, layer):
        # e.g: if layer == 0, layer in bias_weights is 0
        layer -= 1
        weights_matrix = np.random.rand(self.layers[layer + 1]).dot(
            np.sqrt(2 / (self.layers[layer] + self.layers[layer + 1])))
        self.bias_weights.insert(layer, weights_matrix)

    def set_input(self, inputs):
        self.activated_sums.append(inputs)

    @staticmethod
    def activation_sigmoid(sums, derivative=False):
        for i in range(len(sums)):
            if sums[i] > 37:
                sums[i] = 37
            elif sums[i] < -37:
                sums[i] = -37

        s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-sums))
        if derivative:
            return s * (1 - s)
        else:
            return s

    @staticmethod
    def activation_softmax(sums):
        exp = np.exp(sums)
        return exp / exp.sum()

    def propagate(self):
        for layer in range(len(self.weights)):
            # Calculate Sum w*x + b
            zl = self.weights[layer].dot(self.activated_sums[layer])
            np.add(zl, self.bias_weights[layer], out=zl)
            # Saving Sums of (w*x + b) for use in calculating the error of 
              each node in backprop

            self.derivative_sums.append(zl)

            if layer == len(self.weights) - 1:
                al = self.activation_softmax(zl)
            else:
                al = self.activation_sigmoid(zl)

            self.activated_sums.append(al)

    def backprop(self, target_vector):
        for layer in range(len(self.weights) - 1, -1, -1):
            if layer == len(self.weights) - 1: # If layer is output layer: 
                 # calculate derivative w.r.t Output sum vector (∂J/∂z)
                 # [J = Loss function , z = Sum vector before activation]
                self.derivative_sums[layer] = np.subtract(self.activated_sums[len(self.activated_sums)-1], target_vector)
            else:
                # Calculate Error of each Node in layer
                derivative_sigmoid = self.activation_sigmoid(self.derivative_sums[layer], derivative=True)
                sum_errors_in_next_layer = np.sum(self.derivative_sums[layer + 1].dot(self.weights[layer + 1]))
                self.derivative_sums[layer] = np.multiply(sum_errors_in_next_layer, derivative_sigmoid)

        for layer in range(0, len(self.weights) - 1):
            # Stochastic Gradient Descent, Update weights.
            self.SGD(layer)
        
        # Calculate Error of model in iteration n
        self.calc_J(target_vector)
        # Reset Activated_sums, derivative_sums for next iteration.
        self.activated_sums = []
        self.derivative_sums = []



    def SGD(self, layer):
        gradient_error = np.multiply(np.outer(self.derivative_sums[layer], self.activated_sums[layer].T), self.learning_rate)
        self.weights[layer] = np.subtract(self.weights[layer], gradient_error)
        if self.bias_weights[layer] is not 0:
            self.bias_weights[layer] = np.subtract(self.bias_weights[layer], np.multiply(self.derivative_sums[layer], self.learning_rate))

    def calc_J(self, hot_vector):
        x = -np.sum(hot_vector * np.log(self.activated_sums[len(self.activated_sums) - 1]))
        print(x)
        self.error.append(x)

    def graph_loss(self):
        x = self.error
        y = [i for i in range(len(self.error))]
        plt.plot(y, x) # x axis -> Loss, y axis -> epochs
        plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mndata = MNIST('samples', gz=True)
    images, labels = mndata.load_training()

    NN = Neural_Re([784, 200, 200, 10])
    NN.learning_rate = 0.001
    iter = 2000

    for i in range(iter):
        image = np.multiply(mndata.process_images_to_numpy(images[i]), 1 / 256)
        # label vector
        label = [0 for j in range(10)]
        label[labels[i]] = 1

        print(i)
        NN.set_input(image)
        NN.propagate()
        NN.backprop(label)
    NN.graph_loss()
```

Originally, I expected to get something like this (Graph information doesn't matter, only for context):
[image: Expected:]
<sub>(source: [github.io](http://cs231n.github.io/assets/nn3/loss.jpeg))</sub>

But, when I let my Neural Network run (2000 Training Samples):
[image: result:]

Why is the neural network not converging to anything?
Any answers will be appreciated!

**Edit 1:** *Changed Line in Backprop "Calculate Derivative w.r.t ___"*

**Edit 2:** *Added Learning rate [Wasn't the full problem, still doesn't work]*

**Edit 3:** *added Reset statements for activated_sums and Derivative_Sum arrays [Caused problem of stacking inputs, which didn't fix it]*

Comment: I doubt this is the full issue, but it seems like you aren't using your learning rate.

Comment: I'm also confused about your softmax derivative is output -  predicted.  I expected something like this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235528/backpropagation-with-softmax-cross-entropy.  But maybe I'm missing something.  I might be able to help better if you explained that.

Comment: Edited My Comment (In the code [output - predicted]) so my post would be clearer.